# How to create dynamic table on button click in ASP.Net

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a table as follows

```
<table id="Table" runat="server">
            <tr>
                <td>Title <span class="astrix">*</span>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:DropDownList name="ddltitle" ID="ddlDirectorsDetalTitle" runat="server">
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Mr">Mr</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Mrs">Mrs</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Ms">Ms</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Miss">Miss</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Dr">Dr</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Prof">Prof</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Adml">Adml</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Att">Att</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Brig">Brig</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Brn">Brn</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Bshp">Bshp</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Capt">Capt</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Cmdr">Cmdr</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Clr">Clr</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Col">Col</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Comm">Comm</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Cpl">Cpl</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Dame">Dame</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Est">Est</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Flt">Flt</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Fr">Fr</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="GCpt">GCpt</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Hon">Hon</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Jdg">Jdg</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Lady">Lady</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Lt">Lt</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="LtCl">LtCl</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Maj">Maj</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Mdm">Mdm</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Msrs">Msrs</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Mstr">Mstr</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Pstr">Pstr</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Rab">Rab</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Rev">Rev</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Sen">Sen</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Sgt">Sgt</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Sir">Sir</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Sr">Sr</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="WCmd">WCmd</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Name <span class="astrix">*</span>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtDirectorsDetailsFirstName" runat="server" placeholder="First Name"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtDirectorsDetailsLastName" runat="server" placeholder="Last Name"></asp:TextBox><br />
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator28" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtDirectorsDetailsFirstName" ErrorMessage="Required!" ForeColor="Red" ValidationGroup="TabDirectorsDetails" SetFocusOnError="True" />
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp
                                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator29" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Required!" ForeColor="Red" ControlToValidate="txtDirectorsDetailsLastName" ValidationGroup="TabDirectorsDetails" SetFocusOnError="True" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Authorised signatory on the account <span class="astrix">*</span>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioAuthorisedSignatory" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Vertical">
                        <asp:ListItem Selected="True">Yes</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>No</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:RadioButtonList>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Role in Company <span class="astrix">*</span>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:DropDownList name="ddlRole" ID="ddlRole" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true">
                        <asp:ListItem Value="0">Select</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="1">Director</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="2">Sole Director & Company Secretary</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="3">Company Secretary</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="4">Other</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator30" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Required!" ForeColor="Red" ControlToValidate="ddlRole" InitialValue="0" ValidationGroup="TabDirectorsDetails" SetFocusOnError="True" />

                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr runat="server" id="trOtherRole">
                <td></td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtOtherRole" runat="server" placeholder="Others"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator31" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Required!" ForeColor="Red" ControlToValidate="txtOtherRole" ValidationGroup="TabDirectorsDetails" SetFocusOnError="True" />

                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

on a button click I want to create same table again. How can I do this can anyone help please?
I tried cloning the entire `div` in which `table exist` by using the following javascript

```
<script>
    function duplicate() {
        var original = document.getElementById('service');
        var rows = original.parentNode.rows;
        var i = rows.length - 1;
        var clone = original.cloneNode(true); // "deep" clone
        clone.id = "duplic" + (i); // there can only be one element with an ID
        original.parentNode.insertBefore(clone, rows[i]);
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

but not able to do the needful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it something like this.Create empty table with id '`SecondTable`'.

```
function duplicate(){
var source = document.getElementById('Table');
var destination = document.getElementById('SecondTable');
var copy = source.cloneNode(true);
copy.setAttribute('id', 'SecondTable');
destination.parentNode.replaceChild(copy, destination);
}
```

**UPDATE**

Create table dynamically with following and you can create N numbers of tables.

```
var table = document.createElement("TABLE");
```

**UPDATE 2**

**(This way you can generate random and unique ids)**

```
var table = document.createElement("TABLE");
table.id = "table_" + new Date().getTime().toString();
```

Comment: Instead of 2 tables can i repeat it for n numbers of tables??

Comment: Yes, for that you have add table via code dynamically and get id of that table as a destination.

Comment: here the problem is `ID` of content of both the `Tables` are same where as I want different `ID` so that i can fetch the values from it later on

Comment: You can generate ID as a random string before creating table and assign it afterwards.

Comment: Can you please elaborate how to do it? It will be very helpful

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98647/discussion-between-navy-and-hemal).

Answer (score 0):

try this....

```
function duplicate() {
    var tbl= document.getElementById('Table');
    var html="<table id='duplic"+document.getElementById('service').getElementsByTagName('table').length+1+"'>"+tbl.innerHTML+"</table>";
    document.getElementById('service').innerHTML=document.getElementById('service').innerHTML+html;
    return false;
}
```